# Comparing function pointers in javascript

Tags: javascript, pointers

Is there any way to comparing function pointers in javascript? Basically, I want to see if I've added the same function multiple times to an array, and then only add it once. Yeah, I can program my way around it, but it would be much easier to do it this way.

The code below does NOT use an array, but illustrates the point I'm trying to make. I'd like for oldPointer to only be set if a myPointer is a different function.

Here is some example code:

```
function test()
{
}


test.prototype.Loaded = function()
{
   this.loaded = true;
}

test.prototype.Add = function(myPointer)
{
    if (this.oldPointer != myPointer)  //never the same
    {
      this.oldPointer = myPointer;
    }
}

test.prototype.run = function()
{
   this.Add(this.Loaded.bind(this));

   this.Add(this.Loaded.bind(this));  //this.oldPointer shouldn't be reassigned, but it is
}

var mytest = new test();
test.run();
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more pseudocode? I'm not entirely sure what it is you're trying to do. Where is the array? You've not got an array in the entire thing. Additionally, why declare mytest if you're just going to run test.run() anyways?

Comment: The array isn't the point. The above code illustrated what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I disagree. The array is what you want. You want to make sure you've not added it to the array before now. Anyways, you have an answer, so I'll not bother with petty implementation details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming bind is a function that uses Function.apply() to create a function closure binding `this` to the context, `this.Loaded.bind(this)` will produce a new function every time it is called. That is why your code does not work. Unfortunately there is no way to reference `this.Loaded` from the function object produced by bind(), so comparison is impossible.

If instead you did something like the below, your check would work, though I'm not sure how much use it would be to you.

```
test.prototype.run = function()
{
   var loadedFn = this.Loaded.bind(this);
   this.Add(loadedFn);

   this.Add(loadedFn);
}
```

Please clarify exactly what you are trying to do if you want a better answer.

Comment: `bind` is already in `Function` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) but you're right anyway.

Comment: Oops, had no idea Function.bind existed. Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that bind produces a new function every time it's called.  However, your example doesn't solve my problem, since Add appearing twice in the same function was just for ease of illustration. What if I call "run" twice? Basically, no matter how many times run is called, I want this.oldPointer to only be assigned once. Any ideas?

Comment: You could modify Add to accept the context without binding, so it would be `test.prototype.Add = function(myPointer, context)`. Store both values and compare them individually in Add, and bind the context later when you want to execute the function. There are many other options, involving storing extra information or altering your code pattern, and the best solution would be dependent on what you are trying to do. However, it would be good practice to avoid getting into a situation where you would need to perform this check and just make sure you don't call Add twice with the same function.

Comment: Doing it without bind might be the answer, thanks. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Agree about the good practice...to a point. If the contortions you have to make to avoid this situation result in unreadable code, then write something more elegant. In this case, I'd rather have clean code than code that avoids adding a function pointer twice.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is "How do I efficiently avoid adding the same function to a given array twice?" the simplest way to program around it is obviously:

```
// Add f to a if and only if it is not already in a
if (a.indexOf(f) < 0) {
    a.push(f);
}
```

If the linear complexity of `indexOf` bothers you, and you are only concerned about a single array, you can get very fancy and store the fact that the function was loaded in the function itself:

```
// Add f to a if and only if it is not already in a
if (! f.alreadyAddedToA) {
    a.push(f);
    f.alreadyAddedToA = true;
}
```

Pick any name for the hack property.

If there are multple arrays you are worried about, you can store a kind of hashmap (hacked objects in JS, with suitable keys) inside the function.

Comment: all native objects in js are hashmaps

Comment: Doesn't this just kick the can down the road? indexOf(f) uses == under the hood, so if == doesn't work, indexOf will always return -1

Comment: The second example you use works, but ugh, isn't alreadyAddedToA static? What if I did this.   var test = new test(); test.run(); var test2 = new test(); test2.run();  Wouldn't your second example fail too?

Comment: Regarding the implementation using `indexOF`, woops yes I had the operator wrong!  Fixed.

Comment: Regarding the comment on `alreadyAddedToA` I'm not sure I followed the question.  It talked about checking to see if a function was added more than once to an array, so that is what I answered.  From your comment it appears that you are trying to set the `oldPointer` property of a runnable `test` object the first time and only the first time it is run.  Is that right?  What is not working for you?  I'm afraid I am a little confused.

Comment: Okay, but in your version, I'd need a static property for EVERY function added to the array. What if I wanted to add fifty functions? A hundred?